# Search a randomly generated array for how many times a singular random number is present within the initial array

Tags: java, arrays, random, methods

I have printed my array of 20 integers and then printed a single random number after this. I need to search/count the initial array for how many times the single # is present. So far I have been able to all but search/count for the single random number, it continues to search for any random number within the first array and count that number rather than searching for my single #.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
class Main{
public static final Random RND_GEN = new Random();

public int[] createNum(int[] randomNumbers) {
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
        randomNumbers[i] = RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1;
    }
    return randomNumbers;
}

public void printNum(int[] randomNumbers){
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Number " + i + " : " + randomNumbers[i]);
    }
}


public void searchArray(int[] randomNumbers,int numSearch) {
    int count = 0;
    System.out.println("Single # is: " + (RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1));
    for (int i : randomNumbers) {
        if (i == numSearch) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        System.out.println("Single #" + numSearch + " was not found!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Single # "+ numSearch + " was found " + count + " times");
    }
}


public void run() {
    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 1;
    do {
        int[] numbers = new int[20];
        numbers = createNum(numbers);

        printNum(numbers);

        int numSearch = RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1;
        searchArray(numbers, numSearch);
        System.out.print("Restart Program?, Enter 1 for YES, 2 for NO: ");
        x = inputReader.nextInt();
    } while (x == 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main go = new Main();
    go.run();
}
}
```

Comment: Your print in searchArray is incorrect `System.out.println("Single # is: " + (RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1));` should be printing out numSearch. I think your code works fine otherwise?

Comment: @Mike I would kiss you right now if I could..no homo, you just solved a 6 hr problem for me in one sentence...